# Add two properties in nested array of object

Tags: javascript

I've an array of objects:

```js
const arr = [
  {

    "topicId": 1,
    "topicName": "Topic 1",
    "topicIcon": {
      "name": "Caret",
      "class": "lmnicon lmnicon-caret-right"
    },
    "topicContent": "T1 topic content",

    "children": [
      {
        "topicId": 4,
        "topicName": "Topic 4",
        "topicIcon": {
          "name": "Caret",
          "class": "lmnicon lmnicon-caret-right"
        },
        "topicContent": "T4 topic content"

      },
      {
        "topicId": 5,
        "topicName": "Topic 5",
        "topicIcon": {
          "name": "Caret",
          "class": "lmnicon lmnicon-caret-right"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "topicId": 6,
            "topicName": "Topic 6",
            "topicIcon": {
              "name": "Caret",
              "class": "lmnicon lmnicon-caret-right"
            }
          },
          {
            "topicId": 7,
            "topicName": "Topic 7",
            "topicIcon": {
              "name": "Caret",
              "class": "lmnicon lmnicon-caret-right"
            }
          },
          {
            "topicId": 8,
            "topicName": "Topic 8",
            "topicIcon": {
              "name": "Caret",
              "class": "lmnicon lmnicon-caret-right"
            }
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "topicId": 2,
    "topicName": "Topic 2",
    "topicIcon": {
      "name": "Caret",
      "class": "lmnicon lmnicon-caret-right"
    },
    "topicContent": "T2 topic content",

    "children": [
      {
        "topicId": 9,
        "topicName": "Topic 9",
        "topicIcon": {
          "name": "Caret",
          "class": "lmnicon lmnicon-caret-right"
        }

      },
      {
        "topicId": 10,
        "topicName": "Topic 10",
        "topicIcon": {
          "name": "Caret",
          "class": "lmnicon lmnicon-caret-right"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]

const mapHeirarchy = list => list.flatMap(({ topicId, topicName, topicIcon,  children = [] }) => {
  const obj = {
    'topicId': topicId,
    'topicName': topicName,
    'topicIcon': topicIcon,
    'droppable': true, //add this
    'draggable': true  //add this
  }
  return [obj, ...mapHeirarchy(children)]
});
console.log(mapHeirarchy(arr))
```

I need to add this two properties `droppable` and `draggable` as true in objects as well as in nested childrens which might be 'n' levels deep.

Though I added the properties but I need to go back to the original 'arr' structure.

I'm not sure how can we go back or is there more correct way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply `map` instead of getting a flat array.

```js
const
    array = [{ topicId: 1, topicName: "Topic 1", topicIcon: { name: "Caret", class: "lmnicon lmnicon-caret-right" }, topicContent: "T1 topic content", children: [{ topicId: 4, topicName: "Topic 4", topicIcon: { name: "Caret", class: "lmnicon lmnicon-caret-right" }, topicContent: "T4 topic content" }, { topicId: 5, topicName: "Topic 5", topicIcon: { name: "Caret", class: "lmnicon lmnicon-caret-right" }, children: [{ topicId: 6, topicName: "Topic 6", topicIcon: { name: "Caret", class: "lmnicon lmnicon-caret-right" } }, { topicId: 7, topicName: "Topic 7", topicIcon: { name: "Caret", class: "lmnicon lmnicon-caret-right" } }, { topicId: 8, topicName: "Topic 8", topicIcon: { name: "Caret", class: "lmnicon lmnicon-caret-right" } }] }] }, { topicId: 2, topicName: "Topic 2", topicIcon: { name: "Caret", class: "lmnicon lmnicon-caret-right" }, topicContent: "T2 topic content", children: [{ topicId: 9, topicName: "Topic 9", topicIcon: { name: "Caret", class: "lmnicon lmnicon-caret-right" } }, { topicId: 10, topicName: "Topic 10", topicIcon: { name: "Caret", class: "lmnicon lmnicon-caret-right" } }] }],
    droppable = true,
    draggable = true,
    mapHierarchy = list => list.map(({ children = [], ...o }) => ({
        ...o, 
        droppable, 
        draggable,
        ...(children.length && { children: mapHierarchy(children) })
    }));
    
console.log(mapHierarchy(array));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina :), just wanted cue from you I need to delete empty children's array `children:[]` within this function itself if children exists and length is zero

Comment: @Urvashi, please see edit with a default array and a length check.